Is it possible to have Supabase perform a task on a timer triggered by the user?
For example, I'm building a saas app that has that a batch function on the frontend that allows a user to create up to 300 records at a time they see fit. It's a bit more complex than that, there's business logic and calls to external apis but what is the best way this can be achieved using supabase?
It's my understand supabase does not have a batch job functionality built in, right? My initial fit thought was to just use my own nodejs/express api, and build my own endpoints. Seemed straightforward, but authentication is where I honestly got scared. I need to make sure my endpoints and user login (magic links) are done securely and cannot be penetrated easily. Because of this I started leaning more towards Supabase auth and now looking at the other things Supabase can do.
I'd love to know your thoughts, thank you in advance.
